# Hide item in slicer from end user (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a data set on sales with a column named "Processes". This column has four entries: "Budget", "Forecast 1", "Forecast 2" and "Realized".

I have then inserted a slicer on this column, and I would like to always have "Realized" selected and then removed from the filter such that the end user

1. only can filter on "Budget", "Forecast 1" and "Forecast 2"
2. can't deselect "Realized".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct option for your purpose. But you can achieve the requirement with some workaround as stated below-

**Step-1:** Create a new **Disconnected (not related to any table)** table **new_slicer_table_name** contains only three value "Budget", "Forecast 1" and "Forecast 2".

**Step-2:** Create a slicer using **Processes** column from that new table. You will have 3 values in the slicer list now.

**Step-3:** Put a note below the slicer like "*Realized Default Selected"

**Step-4:** Now create a measure as below-

```
show_hide = 

var current_row_process = MIN(your_data_table_name[Processes])

return 
IF(
    current_row_process IN ALLSELECTED(new_slicer_table_name[Processes])
    || current_row_process = "Realized",
    1,
    0
)
```

**Step-5:** Add a visual level filter for the last created measure **show_hide** and show values only when show_hide = 1

This will now give you your expected output.