# Power BI Hide Item in Slicer from End User

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, slicers

In Power BI, I have a page where I want to be able to toggle between two budget scenarios (called "Original Budget" and "BT Savings Budget") and compare against actual expenses (called "Actuals"). I need to have a slicer that shows my two budget scenario options but does not show the Actuals option (I want the Actuals scenario to always be selected). I have set up a slicer using a disconnected table that works beautifully with the underlying data (I mimicked the solution here [Hide item in slicer from end user (Power BI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66278928/hide-item-in-slicer-from-end-user-power-bi)). The problem is that it only works when I have the Source (actual/original budget/BT savings budget) field included in my table. When I remove Source from my table, I get erroneous results. How do I make this slicer setup work without including the Scenario field in my table?

After reading the link above, I created a measure called show_hide that returns 1 if the Source field matches the slicer selection and 0 if the Source field does not match the slicer. The "Actuals" Source scenario always returns 1. When I have the Source field embedded in my table, I get the correct results, but when I remove the Source field, I'm assuming the measure can't grab that detail, so it calculates incorrectly.

How do I make this work??

[image: Photo showing how the show_hide measure works in a table with/without Source field]

[image: Similar photo, different slicer selection]

Adding photos of what my goal is for a chart visual that does not include the source field.
[Similar chart from Tableau Act vs Bud by Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXKOg.png)
[Chart built in PBI Act vs Bud by Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEb4C.png)

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could show the unexpected result as well as the code for the measure. The step 5 of the referred solution makes it work by using the measure as a filter (1 to show vs 0 to hide). The measure connects/compares the selection from the slicer with the current row as well as setting the always-on option to 1.  (Theoretically, in the slicer table you can put anything you want, as long as it “covered“/handled by the measure accordingly.) It seems you may need to double-check your measure here.

Comment: The slicer table should contain the selectable options only. I reckon, you need to “invert“ the measure’s IF clause from the referred solution for yours to work: if NOT ( … in ALLSELECTED(…)) || “Actual“ get 0 otherwise 1

Comment: Here's what the show_hide measure is made of: show_hide = var current_row_scenario = max('Combined Act + Bud'[Source]) return IF(current_row_scenario in ALLSELECTED(Tbl_Budget_Scenarios[Budget Scenario]) || current_row_scenario = "Actuals",1,0)

Comment: I do have a filter on the visual for show_hide, and the whole thing works perfectly when the Source column is included in the visual. I do have a slicer that only contains the two options "Original Budget" and "BT Savings Budget", which is what I want. If you still believe I need to invert the measure's IF clause, would you mind showing me specifically what it should look like? I am new to PowerBI (however not new to coding/data analysis/visualization in general), so I'm still learning exactly how the language works.

Comment: The images in my original post show each of the slicer selections and how they work (the top table in each image shows the expected/intended result, whereas the bottom table in each image shows how the result becomes erroneous when I remove the Source field from the visual).

Comment: Hi Meredith, I realized I misunderstood you before (you mentioned not showing ‘actual’ in the slicer but in the table visual, I misread you don’t want it in the table.) After a few times reading, I hope, my understanding is correct now:

Comment: My understanding is your ‘Table Visual’ should show 2 rows: 1. either of the selected budget and 2. always the actual numbers.

Comment: Your screenshot of the ‘table visual’ shows that your measure [show_hide] calculates the 1 and 0 as intended  In order just to show the rows/lines where [show_hide] = 1, you just select your ‘table visual’ and check the pane section on the right called “Filters” (next to “Visualization” and “Data” panes). Under the headline ‘Filters on this visual’ look for “box” for [show_hide]. There you can select to show items only if it’s equal to 1

Comment: To get rid of [show_hide] in the table visual: in the ‘Filters on this visual’ you will find below the fields applied to the visual the box ‘Add data field here’. First, you may want take [show_hide] off from the table visual. Then you want drag [show_hide] from the Data pane to this ‘Add data field here’ for the table visual and select show items when value equals 1 or filter for 1. This way, [show_hide] is still applied as filter while not showing up in the table visual.

Comment: To answer, what happens if you remove the source field from the table visual: this source field not only creates the rows according to the different data (Original Budget, BT Budget, Actual), the content of each rows works as filter as the same time. So, by removing it, you will get one line with the aggregation (e.g. sum) for all source field categories (or: without source field acting as a filter at all).

Comment: So the numbers in your screenshot of this second table visual matches with the total from the first table visual. This works only if there is a relation among the fields. So, if you remove the source field, but keep the [show_hide] in the table_visual, regardless whether it’s 1 or 0, the table visual shows the same result, because in your data table/data model there is no relationship/connection to the other columns (except for the source field, which is not present in the ‘one-liner’ table visual)

Comment: If you want to have just one row or one column to show the result, this depends on how you data source table is organized. I suspect it’s like a matrix, similar to the table visual of your screen shot. If so, the fastest solution is to add another column in your source table, e.g. called [Amount] which contains the amount for the different source fields. Then choose this one column in the table visual instead of the other columns with the sums by category.

Comment: Thanks so much for your feedback! I do actually have another column called Value which contains the amount for each of the different source fields (so each line of data has dollars in the Value field AND one of the three other (actual, original budget, or BT savings budget) fields. The slicer filtering works fine anytime I have that Source field inside the visual. The problem comes when I remove the Source field, so the show_hide measure can't properly calculate. So, if I have a table, I can work around the issue. However, when I try to translate this into charts, I'm running into trouble...

Comment: @Anonymous I added sample charts to my original post to hopefully clarify what my end goal is. If you have any feedback or could point me in the right direction for building out these charts and be able to flip between my two budget scenarios, I would appreciate it!

Comment: @ Meredith : to put them into a chart that resembles your reference I would do it differently: you can define a field parameter to choose from/switch between the 2 budgets values. Pick a combo chart where actual is represented by a bar and the field parameter is assigned to a line. The trick is to adjust the line that the points are not connected and choose a dash line instead of a point. This is as close as it gets with the standard charts. Otherwise you may want to check those custom charts e.g. so-called lipstick-chart(?) Also, put the field parameter to a slicer to choose from.

Comment: @Anonymous it took a little bit of trial and error, but I think I got it to work with the parameter option. Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Congrats! No worries!